# Automated grading with mathematica

Tags: education

I will use Mathematica in teaching university courses. Is there a way to set up quizzes and automated grading. If so, can you point me to the documentation?

Comment: There is [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1360762) page on the Wolfram Community, though I haven't looked at the notebook myself. Perhaps it can act as a starting point?

Comment: Here's a commercial product (I have not tried it): https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&p=5&v=2477, https://www.sylva.ac/product/features

Comment: Thanks @MassDefect and Michael E2.